Detect left mouse click in message list area in Thunderbird via add-on extension
I am trying to write a Mozilla Thunderbird add-on extension that detects a left mouse click on any empty space of the message list area. My content_script.js file is the following:
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const messagePane = document.getElementById('messagepane');
    const messageList = document.getElementById('threadTree');
    if (messageList.contains(event.target) && !messagePane.contains(event.target)) {
        console.log('Clicked!');
    }
});

This does not work. That is, when I temporarily load the add-on in Thunderbird and inspect it, nothing is printed to the log when I left click on an empty space in the message list area.
What modifications does my code require to achieve my aim? Are any permissions required? Are the IDs correct?

Does the click listener fire at all? To test that, you can just add a console.log statement outside the if statement

Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but that did not work. All I have is a manifest.json script and the above content_script.js script. The only permissions I have in the former are messageRead and activeTab.
